# Notepad++ Replicate text in a line with a change and a variable

Tags: notepad++

Working on editing an .ini file and need to add parameters for a second resolution.  The below data occurs 70x in the ini and the numbers after the = are all different for each line.

What is currently in the file.

```
XPos1920x1030=1280
YPos1920x1030=822
Width1920x1030=431
Height1920x1030=206
```

I need to add 4 additional lines with different parameters before the = while retaining the original locations after the = and placing them into the new line.  This would reflect what needs to occur 70X times.  Note that the 5-8th lines need to change from 1030 to 1150.

```
XPos1920x1030=1280
YPos1920x1030=822
Width1920x1030=431
Height1920x1030=206
XPos1920x1150=1280
YPos1920x1150=822
Width1920x1150=431
Height1920x1150=206
```

Comment: Find: `(?m)^PARAM1=(\d+)\s+^PARAM2=(\d+)\s+^PARAM3=(\d+)\s+^PARAM4=(\d+)` Replace: `$0\nNEW_PARAM1=$1\nNEW_PARAM2=$2\nNEW_PARAM3=$3\nNEW_PARAM4=$4`